# Rotated Digits in Python

Tags: python

I have came across to the following question, my solution passed the initial input, but failed in the following test case. I wonder what I am missing.

The question is described as follows

X is a good number if after rotating each digit individually by 180 degrees, we get a valid number that is different from X.  Each digit must be rotated - we cannot choose to leave it alone.

A number is valid if each digit remains a digit after rotation. 0, 1, and 8 rotate to themselves; 2 and 5 rotate to each other; 6 and 9 rotate to each other, and the rest of the numbers do not rotate to any other number and become invalid.

Now given a positive number N, how many numbers X from 1 to N are good?

**Example:**

**Input:** 10

**Output:** 4

**Explanation**:

There are four good numbers in the range [1, 10] : 2, 5, 6, 9.
Note that 1 and 10 are not good numbers, since they remain unchanged after rotating.

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotatedDigits(self, N):
        """
        :type N: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        rotatedDigits = [2,5,6,9]
        count = 0
        isValid = False
        for i in range(1,N+1):
                for b in str(i):
                    if int(b) in rotatedDigits:
                        isValid = True
                    else:
                        isValid = False
                        break
                if isValid:
                    count +=1
        return count
```

**Input:**
857

**Output:**
68

**Expected:**
247

Comment: Debugging is generally your responsibility, but I will be nice and note that 1 and 0 can be involved in a good number. The check for "same" should be done after performing the replacements on the whole number.

Comment: You're not checking for any of the "bad" numbers. Also your placement of `isValid` and the `break` don't seem correct.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Why 0 and 1 can be involved? In the given example,they did not take into account these digits.

Comment: @pault, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the original problem, 2105 becomes 5102, which is different. Yes, there is also a logic error involving isValid, but that's debugging. This isn't a debugging service. Since you are learning python, try using the builtin function "all".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is incomplete. You are checking for the presence of the digits that rotate, which is correct. But the problem statement also says:

> "the rest of the numbers do not rotate to any other number and become invalid"

Thus if the number contains any of the numbers 3, 4, or 7 it is invalid.

Even if you were to add in that check, your `isValid` flag is in the wrong place. It should be reset inside the `for` loop (not set outside of it).

Here's a version of your function that will work:

```
def rotatedDigits(N):
    """
    :type N: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    rotatedDigits = {'2','5','6','9'}
    badNumbers = {'3','4','7'}
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        flag1 = False  # use this to check if the number contains a rotating digit
        flag2 = True  # use this to check if the number contains a bad digit
        for b in str(i):
            if b in rotatedDigits:
                flag1 = True
            elif b in badNumbers:
                flag2 = False
                break

        if flag1 and flag2:
            count +=1
    return count

print(rotatedDigits(857))
#247
```

I also made made `rotatedDigits` and `badNumbers` sets of strings instead of lists of ints. Set lookups are faster than lists, and also this avoids casting to string and back to int.

---

**Update**: A more pythonic version using set operations:

```
def rotatedDigits(N):
    """
    :type N: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    rotatedDigits = {'2','5','6','9'}
    badNumbers = {'3','4','7'}
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        digits = set(str(i))
        count += 1 if (digits & rotatedDigits) and not(digits & badNumbers) else 0
    return count
```

Here we create a set of the characters in the number (`digits`) and use the `&` operator between sets to get the intersection. We increment `count` if the intersection between `digits` and `rotatedDigits` is not empty and the intersection of `digits` and `badNumbers` is empty.

The above function can be further condensed using `sum`, `map`, and a generator expression:

```
def rotatedDigits(N):
    """
    :type N: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    rotatedDigits = {'2','5','6','9'}
    badNumbers = {'3','4','7'}
    count = sum(1 if (x & rotatedDigits) and not (x & badNumbers) else 0 
                for x in map(lambda i: set(str(i)), range(1, N+1)))
    return count
```

Comment: I added some more pythonic versions of the function to my answer. It should be interesting to you to understand them as you learn python. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach by first checking for any of the invalid characters.  Then verify that it does contain at least one of the rotating characters.

```
rotating = {'2','5','6','9'}
invalid = {'3','4','7'}

def rotated(N):
    X=set(str(N))
    if any(digit in X for digit in invalid):
        return False
    if any(digit in X for digit in rotating):
        return True
    return False

def checkall(N):
    count=0
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        if rotated(i): 
            count += 1
    return count

print(checkall(857))
```

Comment: This works. I would suggest 2 improvements. 1) Make `rotating` and `invalid` sets (curly braces instead of square brackets) and 2) get rid of the square brackets inside the call to `any()` (for ex: `any(digit in X for digit in invalid)`). The square brackets makes in a list comp, without it you will have a faster generator expression.

Comment: @pault good catch! I also moved `invalid` and `rotating` to global namespace so they are not re-created on every call

Answer (score 0):

Whit this check

```
if int(b) in rotatedDigits:
    isValid = True
else:
    isValid = False
    break
```

You have missed numbers with digits: 0, 1, and 8. In given example they represented numbers that stay the same but they are valid 
You must miss all numbers with digits 3, 4 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

# using dictionary :

```
def rotatedDigits(N: int):
    count=0
    d={0:0,1:1,2:5,3:-1,4:-1,5:2,6:9,7:-1,8:8,9:6}
    for i in range(1,N+1):
        l=list(str(i))
        res=[]
        for j in l:
            if d[int(j)]!=-1:
                res.append(str(d[int(j)]))
            else:break
        if len(res)==len(l) and int(''.join(res))!=i:
            count+=1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

first, make a list of number[coverted number to string] in d_l then check bad_numbers is present or not then check that d_l is a subset of only valid numbers or not then if any number pass all the conditions it means it's a good number.

```
def rotatedDigits(self, N: int) -> int:
        count = 0
        for d in range(1, N+1):
            d_l = [ch for ch in str(d)]
            if '3' in d_l or '4' in d_l or '7' in d_l:
                continue   
            if set(d_l).issubset({'0', '1', '8'}):
                continue    
            count += 1
        return count
```